# unable to start 2nd Thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-synchronization

As I am new to Java Threads, I was just experimenting with my code. From Kathy' Sierra SCJP book, I learnt about `thread.join()` method. Then I learnt 'bout `Synchronization`. Below is the code in which I used `thread.join()` method instead of making `makeWithdrawal()` method a `synchronized`.

**AccountDanger** class:

```
public class AccountDanger implements Runnable{
    private Account acct=new Account();
    public static void main(String args[])throws InterruptedException{
        AccountDanger r=new AccountDanger();
        Thread one=new Thread(r);
        Thread two=new Thread(r);// unable to start
        one.setName("Fred");
        two.setName("Lucy");
        one.start();
        one.join();// used join() instead of using synchronize keyword.
        two.start();// unable to start
    }
    public void run(){

        for(int x=0;x<5;x++){
            makeWithdrawal(10);
            if(acct.getBalance()<0){
                System.out.println("Account is over-drawn");
            }
        }
    }
    private void makeWithdrawal(int amt){
        if(acct.getBalance()>=amt){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is goint to withdraw");
            try{
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex){}
            acct.withdraw(amt);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" completes the withdrawal");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Not enough in account for "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" to withdraw "+acct.getBalance());
        }
    }
}
```

**Account** class:

```
class Account{
    private int balance=50;
    public int getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }
    public void withdraw(int amount){
        balance=balance-amount;
    }
}
```

But after seeing the output (more than 10 times), I realized that I was unable to start my second thread (thread with the name `Lucy`). Actually, after testing with `two.isAlive()` print statement, I found it to be alive. But why can't i see this `Lucy` thread working? Why is that? can any one help me? Below is the output I get always get:

```
Fred is goint to withdraw
Fred completes the withdrawal
Fred is goint to withdraw
Fred completes the withdrawal
Fred is goint to withdraw
Fred completes the withdrawal
Fred is goint to withdraw
Fred completes the withdrawal
Fred is goint to withdraw
Fred completes the withdrawal
Not enough in account for Lucy to withdraw 0
Not enough in account for Lucy to withdraw 0
Not enough in account for Lucy to withdraw 0
Not enough in account for Lucy to withdraw 0
Not enough in account for Lucy to withdraw 0
```

Comment: Fred is goint to withdraw
Fred completes the withdrawal
Fred is goint to withdraw
Fred completes the withdrawal
Fred is goint to withdraw
Fred completes the withdrawal
Fred is goint to withdraw
Fred completes the withdrawal
Fred is goint to withdraw
Fred completes the withdrawal
Not enough in account for Lucy to withdraw 0
Not enough in account for Lucy to withdraw 0
Not enough in account for Lucy to withdraw 0
Not enough in account for Lucy to withdraw 0
Not enough in account for Lucy to withdraw 0

Comment: Don't put logs in comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: So you learned about `join()`. What does `join()` do? (You can delete your comments.)

Comment: It joins the another thread onto the end. In this case, I think second thread(Lucy) should be joined after thread(fred). Please correct me if I am incorrect.

Comment: Java has a documentation feature called Javadoc. Look up the javadoc of the `Thread` class and read what `join()` does.

Comment: Yaa, it says -- "Waits for this thread to die." So, why not 2nd Thread runs after 1st thread is over or died.

Comment: It does. Look at your logs.

Comment: Oh Yeah!, But can you please tell me, why can't I see `Lucy is going to withdraw`. I can't see this statement until now. Why is it so?

Comment: Look at your code. Obviously `acct.getBalance()>=amt` is false at that moment.

Comment: Oh WoW..Now, I figured out. Thank You very much for clearing my doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No everything is right, but:

you wait for the termination of Thread1 (join wait, until it is finished).

Thread2 will be started, but it is a daemon Thread. There Threads will be terminiated, if the main-Thread is terminated.

Change your code to:

```
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
thread1.join();
thread2.join();
```

Now both Threads will be finished (and work parallel).

**edit**:

Clarification:

```
one.start(); // Starts the execution of the runnable in Thread "one"
one.join();  // Waits for the Runnable to FINISH
two.start(); // after Thread "one" died, Thread "two" starts (no more moneys in the account)
```

join(): 
[Waits for this thread to die.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29)

This is the same as calling everything synchron.

Comment: Which one? (I would use ExecutorsService, but this was a question about Thread2 is not starting. (Did not look, into the withdraw, if it is Threadsafe or not)

Comment: Right, it's not threadsafe. I'm guessing that is why they wanted to use `join()`, misguidedly.

Comment: Only because of the explained behavior. "The second thread is not started". I think it may be startet and terminated immidiatly, or not startet, because the main Thread finished and the JVM shuts down..

Comment: You have to explicitly set the thread as a daemon for it to be a daemon thread (or if it's creator is a daemon thread). Nothing in the code post indicates that. I've asked for clarifications. You can see the program output.